# stopPropogation is not working for dynamically created input form inside a dynamicllay created clickable div

Tags: jquery

I have a div with id "test" and button. When i click on a button, a new div is created with id "new" and a h2 element inside it. Now when i click on the newly created h2 element, i am appending an input form to it. My problem is when i click on the created input box, onClick of h2 is getting called again which i dont want. stopPropagation also does not seem to be working. Please help me.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<button type="button" id="b" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#b").click(function(){
                var html = '<div id="new"><h2>Hi</hi></div>';
                $('#test').append(html);
        });
        $("#test").on('click', "#new", function(e){
                var html = '<input type="text" class="form-control search">';
                $(this).append(html);
        });
        $("#test").on("keyup", ".search", function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                console.log('yes');;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `stopPropagation` for the `keyup` event, not the `click`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b").click(function() {
    var html = '<div id="new"><h2>Hi</hi></div>';
    $('#test').append(html);
  });
  $("#test").on('click', "#new", function(e) {
    var html = '<input type="text" class="form-control search">';
    $(this).append(html);
  });
  $("#test").on("keyup", ".search", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('yes');;
  }).on('click', '.search', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <button type="button" id="b" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</body>

</html>
```